# regex question - replace all newlines that are not preceded by a tab with a space

Tags: ruby, regex

I have to process a block of text, which might have some spurious newlines in the middle of some of the fields.  I want to strip these newlines out (replacing them with spaces), without stripping out the 'valid' newlines, which are always preceded by a `\t`.

So, i want to replace all newlines that are not preceded by a tab with a space.  To make things a little more complicated, if there's a space on either side of the newline then i want to keep it.  In other words, this

```
"one\ttwo\tbuckle my \nshoe\t\t\n"
```

would become

```
"one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n"
```

i.e., with one space between 'my' and 'shoe', not two.

EDIT - some clarification:  the unwanted newlines are in the middle of a piece of regular text.  If there's a space between the words where the newline occurs, i want to keep it.  oherwise, i want to add one in.  Eg

```
"one\ttwo\tbuckle my \nshoe\t\t\n"
=> "one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n"

"one\ttwo\tbuckle my\nshoe\t\t\n"
=> "one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n"

"one\ttwo\tbuckle my \n shoe\t\t\n"
=> "one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n"
```

EDIT 2: a clumsy but working solution i came up with.  I'm not very happy with it, the double-gsubbing seems unelegant.

```
>> strings = ["one\ttwo\tbuckle my\nshoe\t\t\n", "one\ttwo\tbuckle my \nshoe\t\t\n", "one\ttwo\tbuckle my \n shoe\t\t\n"]
=> ["one\ttwo\tbuckle my\nshoe\t\t\n", "one\ttwo\tbuckle my \nshoe\t\t\n", "one\ttwo\tbuckle my \n shoe\t\t\n"]
>> strings.collect{|s| s.gsub(/[^\t]\n\s?/){|match| match.gsub(/\s*\n\s*/," ")} }
=> ["one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n", "one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n", "one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n"]
```

This seems to work better than any of the suggestions below given my now extended requirements about adding/preserving spaces.

Comment: You should clarify your requirements with more examples and what you mean by "keeping" space on either side of the newline. Given `"my \nshoe"`, why do you want one space between `"my"` and `"shoe"` if you want to keep the one that's already there and replace the `\n` with a space?

Answer (score 2):

#### No lookbehind option

You can match:

```
(\G|[^\t])\n
```

And replace with backreference to what group 1 matched.

Here's a Ruby snippet ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/L5cmx)):

```
from = "\none\ttwo\tbuckle my \nshoe\t\t\nx\n\n\t\n\n"
to   = "one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\nx\t\n"

mod  = from.gsub(/(\G|[^\t])\n/, '\1')

puts (mod == to) # true
```

Essentially we either match "something" that's not a `\t`, followed by an `\n`, and replace with only the "something" part (effectively preserving whatever "it" is, but deleting the `\n`), or we can simply continue from previous match using `\G`, to allow `\n` at the beginning of the string or following another deleted `\n`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class `[…]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

  - [Brackets for Grouping and Backreferences `(…)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
  - [Continuing Previous Match `\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)

---

#### Lookbehind option

If the flavor supports lookbehind, you can also match:

```
(?<!\t)\n
```

And simply replace with the empty string.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

With a double-negative (`[^\S\t]` means all whitespace except TAB characters)

```
def fix(str)
  return str.gsub(/([^\t]|^)[^\S\t]+/, '\1 ')
end
```

the following tests

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

require "test/unit"
require "test/unit/ui/console/testrunner"

class MyTestCases < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_after_space
    assert_equal fix("one\ttwo\tbuckle my \nshoe\t\t\n"),
                     "one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n"
  end

  def test_no_whitespace_neighbors
    assert_equal fix("one\ttwo\tbuckle my\nshoe\t\t\n"),
                     "one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n"
  end

  def test_whitespace_surrounded
    assert_equal fix("one\ttwo\tbuckle my \n shoe\t\t\n"),
                     "one\ttwo\tbuckle my shoe\t\t\n"
  end

  def test_leading_newline
    assert_equal fix("\none\ttwo"),
                     " one\ttwo"
  end
end

Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(MyTestCases)
```

all pass:

```
Loaded suite MyTestCases
Started
....
Finished in 0.000412 seconds.

4 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.gsub(/\s*(?<!\t)\n\s*/, " ")
```

Comment: thanks reko.  That doesn't seem to make any difference to my strings: see my edit above.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the regexp, `(<?` is supposed to be `(?<`. Try now again.